# Force Scala traits to be incompatible

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

Is there a way to stop two traits from being mixed into a class together?

I know you can use self type annotations to require that a trait only be mixed into a class of a specific type, but can you use a similar construct to require that the target class NOT mix in a specific trait?

For example:

```
abstract class Collector(p: Boolean)

trait Cache

trait ACache extends Cache { self: Collector => }

trait BCache extends Cache { self: Collector => }
```

Can I require that any implementation of `Collector` mix in `ACache`, `BCache`, or no cache trait whatsoever, but not `ACache` and `BCache` simultaneously?

```
class GoodCollector(p: Boolean) extends Collector(p) with ACache //legal
class BadCollector(p: Boolean) extends Collector(p) with ACache with BCache //illegal
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change your `Cache` like this:

```
trait Cache[A <: Cache[_]]

trait ACache extends Cache[ACache] { self: Collector =>
}

trait BCache extends Cache[BCache] { self: Collector =>
}
```

then:

```
class BadCollector(p: Boolean) extends Collector(p) with ACache with BCache
```

will fail with:

> illegal inheritance;
>    class BadCollector inherits different type instances of trait Cache:
>   Cache[BCache] and Cache[ACache]
>     class BadCollector(p: Boolean) extends Collector(p) with ACache with BCache